# 401 error after succesfull login in VueJs with Vuex and localStorage

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

Im really scratching my head when building my first vue apps. I use Bearer Token authentication and that works fine. The only issue I'm having that when I retrieve a token and save that to for example localstorage. The token is saved, but all next calls are returning a 401. When I refresh the browser, everything starts working.

I added vuex and set the token to the state in vuex. That wont change.

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
 
const store = createStore({
    strict: false,
    state: {
        token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
        isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')
    },
    getters: {},
    mutations: { 
        token(state,payload) {
            state.token = payload
        }
    },
    actions: {} });

export default store
```

Tried to use axios interceptors instead of default.headers, no result.

at Login the localstorage is set and a store commit is done.

Afterwards every request is send with bearer token in Authorization header.

Any idea?

Comment: we would probably be guessing without seeing any code. Is the Bearer Token set once only? or set every time just before the API is used?

Comment: Without seeing your code it is harder to know what exactly to correct. But in your store, the way you initiated your token in the state might be the issue.

Comment: Typically you would use an Axios request interceptor to set the `Authorization` header. If you tried that, you should definitely share the code

Comment: FYI, if you intend for your store to be backed by `localStorage`, you should be setting the value into `localStorage` within your mutation (or action). There's also a nifty plugin you can use that does it for you ~ https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist#readme

Comment: My professional advice is to just use an encrypted session cookie with `httpOnly, secure` flags set ON - all your struggles will be gone: no need for localStorage, no need for interceptors, user is logged out as soon as he/she closes the browser tab.